# Neural Network Unstable Results Time Series

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to set up a Neural Network that, based on returns of the last 260 days of a series of assets, tries to predict which is the likelihood of each single asset falling within the first quartile over the following period in terms of sharpe ratio.

The setting of the network is quite easy, two layers (the first with 30 nodes, the second with 20).

At first sight the results look encouraging too, however there is a problem. if we take for example one single asset, it might happen that if I run the neural network model on it today, it predicts for example 0.8, whereas if I run it tomorrow (so shifting the returns in X by one day) the result change completely.

I wouldn't want this behaviour and would desire some more stable results, considering that the only difference is that one return has changed (the oldest one has gone out, and the yesterday return has entered) and the other 259 has been shifted by 1 day.

Can you please help me?

Comment: could you share a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.